# IntelliJ - pink underlined variable... what does it mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

could you please explain me, why the list-variable in line 108 has this specific color and is underlined?

[image]

If i put the same code in a for-each instead of a foreach(), then it looks "normal".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remember that lambdas are essentially syntactic sugar for an anonymous class implementing a functional interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the first thing you're using lambda which is syntactic sugar. At the second thing the purple underline appears if a variable isn't from inside the lambda to show the user you're not using a local variable.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0;
    Consumer<String> stringConsumer = foo -> {
      foo += a;
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        String s = " " + a;
    }
}
```

If you paste that you'll see that only the `a` in `foo += a` gets purple underlined because it's from outside the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

It's just [semantic highlighting](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/01/make-sense-of-your-variables-at-a-glance-with-semantic-highlighting/) to mark the `entryDTS` isn't a local variable

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/pycharm/files/2017/01/prefs.png))</sub>

> Semantic Highlighting, previously introduced in KDevelop and some other IDEs, is now available in IntelliJ IDEA. It extends the standard syntax highlighting with unique colors for each parameter and local variable

Answer (score 0):

The underlined parameter indicates that a local variable is declared outside and used inside a lambda expression.
To disable it go to: Editor -> Color Scheme -> Java -> Parameters -> disable "Implicit anonymous class parameter"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhGgF.png)